# Angular 5 Circular Dependency: Component in Component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular5

I'm currently in a project where we have a dynamic "form"/content model where we have what we call a module which contains fields and placeholders, and placeholders can contain more modules, giving us a recursive/flexible data model.

Now to render this we have created one component for rendering the module, with dynamic rendering for different field types and then a for-loop to render placeholders which is its own component.

The circular dependency I get is `module.component -> placeholder.component -> module.component`

A quick setup for this can be found at this plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ieV9rjJ8MZLzFpzPaj3L

Running `ng serve` gives no errors but `ng build --prod` does

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src/app/module.component.ngfactory.js -> 
src/app/placeholder.component.ngfactory.js -> 
src/app/module.component.ngfactory.js
```

I guess this is because `ng build --prod` does the AOT build and the circular dependency is in HTML.

The code runs fine however, the real question is if this is considered bad implementation pattern? I'm not sure how to solve it otherwise.

Comment: Got the same issue. Have you figured it out yet?

Comment: @maxisam No, since it was just a warning and not an error we had to just ignore it

Comment: I see. But it is annoying as hell. Thanks.

Comment: I know it's not ideal but you can add `"showCircularDependencies": false` to the architect -> build -> options section of your angular.json file to make the build process look clean until the team addresses it.

Comment: My 5 minutes elapsed, but I wanted to add for those using an older version:

If you are using angular-cli, which you may be with 5, it's in the defaults -> build section. 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

Check this one. https://netbasal.com/recursion-in-angular-components-1cd636269b12

Try adding ***ngIf** when the recursion ends.

Comment: In the article that you link to they only use ONE component, not two that depend on each other